# readf not assigning properly within looped try-catch

Tags: d

If 'a' is typed as input for the program below, instead of an integer, the output goes into a loop without stopping for more input. Why?

```
uint inputInt = 1;
while (inputInt > 0) {
  write("enter something: ");
  try {
    readf(" %s", inputInt);
    writefln("inputInt is: %s", inputInt);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    writeln("does not compute, try again.");
    inputInt = 1;
  }
}
```

I would expect `inputInt` to get assigned '1' in the `catch` block, and then the `try` block to be executed again. However, the output shows that the program does not stop to collect `inputInt` again a second time:

```
enter something: does not compute, try again.
enter something: does not compute, try again.
enter something: does not compute, try again.
enter something: does not compute, try again.
enter something: does not compute, try again.
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when `readf` fails it doesn't remove the input from the buffer. So the next time round the loop it fails again.

Try this:

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
    uint inputInt = 1;
    while (inputInt > 0) {
        write("enter something: ");
        try {
            readf(" %s", inputInt);
            writefln("inputInt is: %s", inputInt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            readln(); // Discard current input buffer
            writeln("does not compute, try again.");
            inputInt = 1;
        }
    }
}
```